# Item shifting slightly when hovering in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have an item that when hovering in IE7 is causing the item below to shift slightly.

You can see the item in question here: http://andovertowncouncil.customstudio.co.uk/

In the right sidebar each item has an H2 heading. When you hover over this in IE7 the item below shifts down by 2/3 pixels. If you then hover over something else, like the button, this lower item returns to its original position.

I've tried to be very specific with my hover effect:

```
.right-item h2 a:hover {
margin-bottom: 5px;
border-bottom: none;
padding-bottom: 0;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 30px;
}
```

But without success.

I'd be grateful for any suggestions on how to solve this one?

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't tell why you're adding the following rules on hover, but they are what is causing your content shifts:

```
.right-item h2 a:hover {
    border-bottom: medium none;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    border-bottom: medium none;
}
```

If removed everything looks good in all browsers.

Comment: Hi Andres, I was adding second a:hover rule to stop links underlining when hovering. You're absolutely right, by removing that rule the problem is solved. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

You're adding `margin-bottom` on hover.

Try removing this and see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: Hi Curt, I was adding margin-bottom to try to match the normal state, as that also has 5px margin-bottom applied. Sadly removing that has no effect, the problem still exists. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @TomPerkins Okay cheers I hadn't spotted that you also had `margin-bottom` applied to the normal state. FYI you don't need to duplicate attributes in your `:hover` state. The browser will automatically inherit the normal state styles, and override with clashing styles in the `:hover` state.

Comment: Thanks for your message. I'm aware that duplicate declarations are redundant, I'd simply added this to see if IE was applying extra margin-bottom on hover. Thanks for your help on this one.